# How do you perform a "one time" data load into Upsolver from a JDCB data source?

Tags: upsolver

I have some historical data that I want to create an Upsolver pipeline with.  This data source is an Oracle table, that I connect to with JDBC.  I want to bring in a "one time" snapshot of this table, so that I can reference it with Upsolver outputs.

I tried creating a JDBC data source, but Upsolver is asking me for an incrementing column, or a timestamp column, of which I have neither.  I tried using a column that included some timestamps, but Upsolver did not ingest the full table.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a JDBC data source in Upsolver, you can specify a "Full Load Interval".  This tells the data source to grab a full copy of the table every N minutes (defined by the parameter).  When the "Full Load Interval" parameter is used, the incrementing column and timestamp columns are not needed.  If you want to only perform a "one time" full snapshot of the table, you can set the full load interval to be an exceptionally high number of minutes so that the full load never happens after it is initially created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).